# Why is this code not starting?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am trying to simulate a Simon Says game. I am currently using Corona SDK, and using Lua as my language.

I have put the `addEventListener(touch)` on the function, "starting". I have tried debugging it and it seems that the code does not correctly run the part that says, `if (started) then` statement. I would be very grateful if you guys were to help lead me to the right direction!

Here's part of my code:

```
 local function starting(event)

    if (started == false) then
        started = true
    end


    if (event.phase == "ended") then
        start()
        startText.isVisible = false
---------------------------------------------------
--THIS BELOW PART IS WRONG-- does not do "started"

        if (started) then

            count = count + 1


            --if started--
            if(math.mod(count,20) == 0) then
                clicked = 0

                if(light >= 0) then
                    light = light - 1
                end

            end
```

Comment: what does "does not correctly run" mean? did you initialize started to false?

Comment: just initialize started = nil, or false.

Comment: False would probably be better than nil. But it doesnt really matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have initialized **started** as false like rpattiso mentioned. Also in my past experience with Lua, sometimes just putting `if (started) then`
does not work for me, so you should try `if (started == true) then`.